# Why are the element of my string list not returning a string when called?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I have these code stumps

Javascript:

```
vidsrc = @IndexModel.vidFilescs[IndexModel.count].ToString()
    function newVid() {
    
    videoplayer.src = vidsrc
    }
```

C#:

```
public static List<string> vidFilescs = new List<string>();
public static int count = 0;
public static void syncVids()
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\source\repos\htmlscreen\vids");
    vidFilescs.Clear();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        vidFilescs.Add(file.ToString());
    }
}
```

When i call vidsrc it returns at element as clear text and i get this error in the browser

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at (index):43:15)
```

I have tried using backticks to call vidsrc in a string.
and as you can see i have tried .ToString() the element.

Comment: You're trying to access a C# variable inside javascript, you can't do this.
Hide your C# variable with @Html.HiddenFor() and then retrieve the value with JS.

Comment: Well it does access it, i get the path, but not as a string.

Comment: the vidsrc is a path to the file at the directory (C:\source\repos\htmlscreen\vids). Count is how many times the newVid() Function is run to keep count of the index, but that is not implemented yet, and it seems i forgot to remove it here from my example

Answer (score 0):

Given the info you gave me I understand now what you're trying to achieve.

This should work:

```
var vidsrc = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(IndexModel.vidFilescs[IndexModel.count]))
```

Note that **IndexModel.count** has to have a value, you said **count** wasn't implemented yet but if you instead use this :

```
var vidsrc = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(IndexModel.vidFilescs[0]))
```

You should get a value back.

Comment: I get:
 'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you add `using System.Text.Json;` to your razor file does it work ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no